# How to notice duplicate geometry?

Tags: mesh, geometry

In responding to a recent question someone told me that my mesh had a lot of "duplicate geometry". At the time I did not really understand the remark but I think I now begin to understand. I also became aware that for instance the extrude tool creates duplicate geometry.

**Question** When looking at my mesh how can I see that there is a lot of duplicate geometry and how to clean that up ?

Comment: Press *A*, *W* > *Remove Doubles*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually doubles and duplicate geometry are unintentional, but sometimes you might have geometry that is intentionally in close proximity to other geometry so that you can't just do a remove doubles on the entire object.

There's a couple of Low-Tech ways that i'd like to suggest first.

- If you press Z, in edit mode, you'll see a transparent / half opaque mesh. Faces that are duplicated in place will often appear darker. 
  [image].
  Keep in mind that Backfacing Faces will also appear darker, so don't get confused :)
- In Object mode, you'll see duplicate edges because they are drawn using the same color as the border of a mesh. Whether or not this is intentional I don't know, but it works well to track down duplicates edges.
  [image]
- In Face selection mode of Edit Mode, look for Dots on edges. Dots indicate the median of a face and should never been visible on edges.
  [image]
  You see this with geometry that you've accidentally extruded without translating the new face.
- In vertex selection mode of Edit Mode, look for vertices which don't highlight surrounding edges:

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

**removing duplicate geometry**

Select everything in edit mode by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>.
Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, click *remove doubles*, and you're done.
It's as easy as that.

[image]

After clicking Remove Doubles, you can set the merge distance by bringing up the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) and going to the bottom.